# Setting up a git repository and attempting to link it to Heroku - parse error in package.json

Tags: git, heroku

`git push heroku master`

I receive :

```
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 3.33 KiB | 1.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Expected separator between values at line 8, column 11
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote: parse error: Expected separator between values at line 8, column 11
remote: parse error: Expected separator between values at line 8, column 11
remote: parse error: Expected separator between values at line 8, column 11
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to evening-springs-83330.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/evening-springs-83330.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-springs-83330.git'
```

I am trying to publish my work through Heroku.

Comment: Did you try correcting the error on line 8 in `package.json`?

Comment: can you update your question and include your `package.json`

Answer (score -1):

parse error: Expected separator between values at line 8, column 11

solved

git add .
git commit -m "fix comma in package.json"
git push heroku master